# GCP to GCP connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, lan, vpc

I am in a situation in which I have to make a rabbitMQ connection (me being a consumer) to a GCP server. My code is also on GCP machine. So both parties (one being MQ producer and other me) decided to create a local network connection rather than going for external IP connection. I have already tried everything but failed to do so. I have successfully done:

1. VPC network creation on both GCP (lets call A & B):Success
2. VPC network peering (A - B) and (B - A) : Success
3. Set up the firewall rule : Success
4. Try ping local address of A (10.x.x.x) from B : failed

Is there anything I am doing wrong here ? Please help.

Thanks,
Sunny

This is my firewall rule on "A":
[image]

Comment: Did you try after a couple of minutes after setting the peering connection? If it was immediate, then that could be the reason of the error. You could also add details of your firewall rules. Are those projects in different organizations?

Comment: @Neri : thank you for your response, I just added the firewall rules. Please help.

Comment: Could you check whether firewall rule configured on both the VPC networks in project A and B. Also how are you testing the ping?  Is it from VM in Project A to VM in Project B?  If yes then could you confirm if there is any firewall configured to block ICMP on the VM level.

Answer (score 9):

Is there a chance your VPC's are in auto-mode?
Custom mode might be required: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc

You plan to connect VPC networks using VPC Network Peering or Cloud VPN. Because the subnets of every auto mode network use the same predefined range of IP addresses, you cannot connect auto mode networks to one another.

Answer (score 4):

There are some restrictions on VPC peering:

- No subnet IP range can overlap across peered VPC networks.
- No subnet IP range can overlap with another subnet IP range in a peered VPC network.

Make sure your subnets do not feature overlapping IP ranges across peered VPCs.

See https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#Restrictions

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean to say two VPC's using us-west1 can not have overlapping subnet IP ranges, or even if in different regions the subnet IP ranges can not overlap?

Comment: For peered VPCs there can be no overlapping subsets or static routes. “A subnet CIDR range in one peered VPC network cannot overlap with a static route in another peered network. This rule covers both subnet routes and static routes. Google Cloud checks for overlap in the following circumstances and generates an error when an overlap occurs.
When you peer VPC networks for the first time
When you create a static route in a peered VPC network
When you create a new subnet in a peered VPC network“

Answer (score 0):

I think if you enable Egress firewall with same values like Ingress traffic, it will work. Ingress firewall is for incoming request and egress is for outgoing request. I know it is very basic but sometimes help.

Answer (score 0):

Check below items:

1. Exchange IPv4 custom routes - [vpc custom routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3qjc.png)
2. firewall rule for icmp (ping testing) or open MQ 5671/5672/15671/15672 (based on your user case)
3. Try GCP network intelligent - conneciton testing - https://cloud.google.com/network-intelligence-center/docs/connectivity-tests/concepts/overview

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc